# Responsive Fixed Sidebar CSS

Tags: html, css

What is the best css way to make sidebar fixed to the left and at the same time to make the rest of the site float to right with the full width (minus the sidebar width, 100px just for example).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="sidebar">
            Should be fixed, full height, 160px Width.
        </div>

        <div class="page-wrapper">
            Should be full width minus the sidebar width
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: .sidebar{
 width: 160px;
 height: 100vh;
 padding: 20px 0;
 float: left;
 z-index: 10;
 position: fixed;
}

Comment: but for the page wrapper, I dont konw how to make it go to the right and to be full width minus the sidebar width. NOTE: I dont want to use float right

Comment: you don't mind if i show you using bootstrap or you wanna me use pure css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) can do that.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 160px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.page-wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <p>Should be fixed, full height, 160px Width.</p>
</div>

<div class="page-wrapper">
  <p>Should be full width minus the sidebar width</p>

</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/feuee0Le/2/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/feuee0Le/1/ Updated the example...look on it know. Sidebar is not fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just made an `example` for you, check this out :

[Side-Content](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbjdgy8o/4/)

**How does it work ?**

Define a main div, in which you are going to have your **Main Contents** and **Side Contents** located, I've called it **Page**, and add these **CSS** properties to it:

```
.page {
    display: table;
    direction: rtl;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Secondly, add your **Main Contents** **CSS** properties as below;

```
.main {
    background: #eee;
    float: right;
    display: table-cell;
    direction: ltr;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
```

And Your **Side Contents** after :

```
.sidebar {
    background: #ccc;
    display: table-cell;
    direction: ltr;
    width: 12em;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
```

Having your `main div` `display` set to `table`, you are letting elements behave like a `table` element, so later on you can call on your `sub-divs`, and by adding `display table-cell`, you are letting the element behave like a `<td>` element, define a particular width for you cells, and have your them allocated next to each other.